# Submit Comments to mySQL using Php

Tags: php

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Insert Comments into Database that user provides
$comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addComment']);
$pID4 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$cID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseInfoDD']);
        $username = "####";
        $password = "####";
        $pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=####', $username, $password);
        $pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('
    INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
    VALUES(:comm, :pID4, :cID);
');
$sth4->execute(array( ':comm' => $comm, ':pID4' => $pID4, ':cID' => $cID, ));

?>
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
```

**DB TABLE:**  http://postimage.org/image/pfkqxpg/

Why isnt this working? Do I need to include professor too??  :: http://postimage.org/image/25wsqhap0/

It seem to not like the line: `$sth4->execute(array( ':comm' => $comm, ':pIDF' => $pID4, ':cID' => $cID ));` do you spot anything wrong? It throws error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' in Stack trace: #0  PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1: require_once('/Applications/X...') #2 {main} thrown on line 75
```

// Moderator Please show pictures since I still dont have rights to

Comment: putting your PDO in a try catch block and echoing the errors might help you. `try { /*your code*/ } catch (PDOException $pe) { echo $pe; }`

Comment: Why do you need to make an image out of text?

Comment: Can you help me with fixing my code please?

Comment: Replace your :named variables with "?" marks and change your array from assoc to a regular one(array($var1,$var2,$var3)).

Comment: Again, please show code sample, I am a bit of a newbie with php :)

Comment: Sorry, on my phone, slow and difficult. `$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);');` `$sth4->execute(array($comm, $pID4, $cID ));`

Comment: This is giving me the "no pID" specified error

Comment: **Error:** `No pID specified.`  That is in the url, how do I make the page able to retain the url upon submission? I feel like that may fix it.

Comment: What's the URL you're submitting? From everything I've see above 'pID' isn't defined.

Comment: The url is a local url with the page being : "prof.php?pID=273"

Comment: Keep in mind this is a dynamic url, based on the value of pID

Comment: To get the pID into your code, look at the PHP $_REQUEST variable. (Google it!)

Comment: How is request different than _POST ? Can you show me in the code I have

Answer (score 1):

```
$sth4->execute(array( 'comm' => $comm, 'pID4' => $pID4, 'cID' => $cID, ));
```

No colons